# Merge two observables from subjects completes too early

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two services with one `Subject` each that are emiting `void` after it completes creating objects. I want to merge them so that my component is informed when either one of the services emit the message.

```
    let subject = new Subject();
    let subject2 = new Subject();

    let obs = subject.asObservable();
    let obs2 = subject2.asObservable();

    obs.subscribe(
      {
        complete: () => console.log('completed obs')
      }
    )

    obs2.subscribe(
      {
        complete: () => console.log('completed obs2')
      }
    )

    merge([obs, obs2]).subscribe(
      {
        next: () => console.log('thanks for info about creating the object I needed, I will cleanup now'),
        complete: () => console.log('completed MERGE')
      }
    )
```

I receive the `completed MERGE` in the console and no `completed obs` or `completed obs2`. Without even emmiting anything. My problem is that this `merge` is completing too early. I want to use those streams (`obs` and `obs2`) for the timelife of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` method does not accept an array. Well it does, but it doesn't do what you expect. When you give an array, it will use `from` to create a stream. This will emit the `obs` and `obs2` as value, and thus resulting in two times the `next` being called. Because the array only has two items, the merge will also `complete`, because everything has been emitted.

Change to `merge(obs, obs2)` and you are good to go.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground-test-jocidc?file=index.ts)

Comment: You just saved me from another 8h of pulling my hair out. Worked as expected. Thanks for explanation and solution. Cheers!